# QUIC protocol on Node.js gRPC library

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node, quic

Is there a way to enable QUIC protocol in Node.js gRPC library? On client side (Android app), I can swap out the transport channel for Cronet's implementation which supports QUIC, but I can't figure out how to enable the protocol on server's side. The Server class does not seem to provide any means for swapping the channel, only passing channel options which have no reference of QUIC protocol in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Node gRPC library does not support the QUIC protocol.